# Pygame crashing

Tags: python, command-line, pygame

I have recently encountered an issue whenever I try and use pygame. The window that comes up hangs and just ends up crashing. I know this program works because I have run it many times before (this also occurs with anything else I try and run in pygame). Strangely, in the command prompt window it asks an input question from a completely unrelated program I was working on last night.

Comment: This sounds like a problem with your environment, not with Pygame.

Comment: With my environment? Everything else works within python, just not the pygame library.

Comment: Probably you have overwritten the wrong file or replaced a symlink.

Comment: "Your environment" here means your local machine. Pygame doesn't run randomly-chosen programs on your computer for no reason.

Comment: Can you post the code? Sometimes this is program related in your event loop and game loop. Programmers can often cause issues by creating too much of a load for the main thread of the program.

Comment: I appear to have solved it. I moved the file that was executing (the unrelated program) into another folder and everything now runs smoothly. I don't understand what the issue was specifically, but pygame now runs fine.

Comment: In that case it probably had something to do with the filenames... as the answers below suggested. It probably found a pygame file in the same directory and took that for the module when it tried to import...

Answer (score 0):

It could be, that you named your file pygame.py, so now, whenever you try to import pygame, it imports from THAT pygame.py file. Maybe delete/rename the file and reinstall pygame would work, i had the same problem a year ago and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a setup problem.

possible solutions:

- rename files (as Mooper suggested)
- create the smallest possible use for pygame (once without / once with windows popping up), in order to tell us where the error comes up / does not.
- look at the code again; seems to me being an error with a neverending loop / overflowing stack  / a function not returning after being called.
- last possible idea: reinstall pygame